# Load sdcard file to html file of assets folder

Tags: android, html, android-assets

I'm trying to load sdcard's image file to assets folder's html file using javascript.If in path i put image src as weblink then it loads the link but if I give image src path as sdacrd file path it doesn't load anything

```
path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"aa.jpg";   
webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/info.html");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:init('" + path + "')");
            }
        });
```

info.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <image  id="img" clip-path="url(#user)" x="210" y="150" height="150" width="150" xlink:href="https://anyfile.jpg" />
        </svg>
    </body>


    <script>
        var imgval=document.getElementById('img');
        function init($path) {
            imgval.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', $path);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

If I give sdcard path it should load from that path only.
Other way I found is just copy this html file to sdcard so that image will get load but I don't want to copy it to sdcard i wanted to load it from sdcard only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format to load image file from SDcard :

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/image_file_in_root_folder.jpg";
```

Comment: how did you tried it? show in an example the file path that you have made. and also do you have permission to read from SDcard? and dos that file exist?

Comment: Sorry my mistake your solution is working absolutely fine.Thank you.